# Hello World socket server

Tags: code-golf, hello-world

Write the shortest program that answers "Hello, World" to a network connection.

Conditions:

- Program shall listen on port 12345
- When a client connects, program shall write "Hello, World" to the newly opened socket connection and then close the connection
- Program shall accept connections in a loop, i.e. handle any number of connects
- Program does not need to handle parallel connections

Test:

```
prompt> telnet localhost 12345
Hello, World
prompt>
```

Comment: This is essentially a less interesting version of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3988

Comment: Does it have to close the connection after the Hello World! Or can it just hang?

Comment: @carusocomputing Second point.

Comment: I just think it's worth pointing out that this question was recently necro'd from 2013.  That only means what it means, but I want to make sure people aren't missing this.

Answer (score 6):

### Bash (34)

```
nc -l 12345 <<<Hello,\ World;. $0
```

Comment: At least one and probably two characters of whitespace there are unnecessary.

Comment: If you mean `nc -l12345<<<Hello`, that doesn't work. nc needs the space between `-l` and `12345`, and removing the space before `<<<` gets `bad file descriptor` from Bash.

Comment: I suppose that `nc` is from BusyBox. The GNU `netcat` requires `-p` switch too. And with my `bash` 4.2.42 there is no such error if you remove the space before `<<<`.

Comment: this is the great thing with bash. you can never be sure that it works on an other machine.

Comment: what does the `. $0` at the end do?

Comment: @professorfish `.` is the same as `source`. So basically it sources itself.

Comment: I don't think this can `handle any number of connects`, as `. $0` will quickly segfault your shell, due to a stackoverflow see [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104930/61904) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 268 Bytes

```
import java.io.*;import java.net.*;
class S{public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception{ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(12345);while(1>0){Socket t=s.accept();PrintWriter u=new PrintWriter(t.getOutputStream());u.println("Hello World!");u.flush();t.close();}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import java.io.*;import java.net.*;
class S{
    public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception{
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(12345);
        while(true) {
            Socket t = s.accept();
            PrintWriter u = new PrintWriter(t.getOutputStream()) ;
            u.println("Hello World!");
            u.flush();
            t.close();
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the "?"? And yours ended up nearly exactly like mine. I guess there's only so many ways to do this in Java.

Comment: The `?` was me contemplating whether or not to post it heh. Also, necrotic?

Comment: Ya, I bumped this from like 3 years ago. Seemed like a good challenge to put back out there. I guess they didn't say count units back then? And whoops, that was a swypo. Meant "nearly".

Comment: Won't `while(1)` work?

Comment: @Carcigenicate maybe in Java 8 not Java 7 though.

Comment: But `for(;;)` will!

Comment: -1 no freehand circle

Comment: @SeeOneRhino I have a tool called "SnagIt" haha. If it's on the computer and overrides my PrtSc button, might as well use it instead of paint!

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl, 78 chars

```
socket -server r 12345;proc r {s a b} {puts $s Hello,\ World;close $s};vwait r
```

the `vwait r` enters the event loop (not necessary with Tk) until the variable `r` is set. 
Usually you use the variable `forever`.
And the `Hello,\ World` is the same as `{Hello, World}` or `"Hello, World"`

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org), 133 bytes

```
package main
import(n"net")
func main(){l,_:=n.Listen("tcp",":12345")
for{c,_:=l.Accept()
c.Write([]byte("Hello, World"))
c.Close()}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## LiveScript (node.js), 73 bytes

```
(require(\net)createServer ->it.write 'Hello, World';it.end!)listen 12345
```

Answer (score 2):

## C# 220

```cs
using System.Text;namespace System.Net.Sockets{class P{static void Main(){var s=new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,12345);s.Start();while(true){using(var c=s.AcceptSocket()){c.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World"));}}}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```cs
using System.Text;
namespace System.Net.Sockets
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var s = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
            s.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                using (var c = s.AcceptSocket())
                {
                    c.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty straightforward. I could have saved 14 characters by removing `IPAddress.Any,` but that would rely on using deprecated API ...

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, <s>153</s> 148 bytes

-5 byte using macros. See comments.

```clj
(let[s(java.net.ServerSocket. 12345)](while 1(with-open[c(.accept s)](doto(java.io.PrintWriter.(.getOutputStream c))(.write"Hello, World").flush))))
```

Full program that listens in a loop for incoming connections, and outputs as required. The Java-interop is killer here. I don't need the same libraries enough to justify an import though.

Pregolfed:

```clj
(defn server []
  (let [ss (java.net.ServerSocket. 12345)]
    (while 1
      ; Auto closes the client
      (with-open [c (.accept ss)]
         ; Passes the PrintWriter as the first argument to each function
         (doto (java.io.PrintWriter. (.getOutputStream c))
           (.write "Hello, World\n")
           ; Parentheses are optional if the function only takes 1 argument
           ; Ugly, but shorter
           .flush)))))
```

Comment: This is basically word-for-word what it'd be in Java but less verbose haha. Clojure is now on my list of things to check out.

Comment: @carusocomputing I can't recommend Clojure enough. Probably the language I'm going to write with for the next few years. It's just awesome.

Comment: Have you tried Groovy :)? It's my favorite for short-hand Java.

Comment: @carusocomputing I think I checked it out at some point, but I didn't like the aesthetics of it. Same reason a haven't learned Ruby yet; I just shudder when I look at it it.

Comment: @carusocomputing I think I was thinking of a different language. It actually looks like of nice.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107414/59376 is my answer ported to Groovy, it's just shorthand Java :).

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, 119 bytes

```
{s=new java.net.ServerSocket(12345);while(1){(u=(t=s.accept()).getOutputStream())<<"Hello, World";u.flush();t.close()}}
```

Port of my java answer.

Comment: Oh ya. Looks like a pretty simple syntax.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the best thing Groovy does is collections manipulations with additions like Python's map and lambda along with shorthand iteration like `1..100.each{println(it)}` or vectorizing commands like `1..100.collect{it/2}` results in 1 through 100 divided by 2 in a list.

Comment: Ya, that's pretty tiny. The Clojure equivalent to the first would be `(mapv println (range 1 100))`, or more correctly `(doseq [n (range 1 100)] (println n))`. Unfortunately, Clojure is far from a good golfing language. I just use it to practice.

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 111 bytes

```rkt
(do([l(tcp-listen 12345)])(#f)(let-values([(i o)(tcp-accept l)])(display"Hello, World"o)(close-output-port o)))
```

It always surprises me when the `do` form is shorter than explicit recursion. I'm not entirely certain if I'm required to close the input port. Please comment if you think I need to.

### Ungolfed

```rkt
(do ([l (tcp-listen 12345)]) (#f)
  (let-values ([(i o) (tcp-accept l)])
    (display "Hello, World" o)
    (close-output-port o)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 103

```
import socket
s=socket.socket()
s.bind(('',12345))
s.listen(1)
s.accept()[0].sendall(b'Hello, World')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 118 bytes

```
$s=new IO::Socket::INET LocalPort=>12345,Listen=>5,Reuse=>1;{$c=$s->accept;$c->send("Hello World");shutdown $c,1;redo}
```

Example:

```
$ perl -MIO::Socket -e '$s=new IO::Socket::INET LocalPort=>12345,Listen=>5,Reuse=>1;{$c=$s->accept;$c->send("Hello World");shutdown $c,1;redo}'

$ telnet localhost 12345
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello WorldConnection closed by foreign host.
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram (102)

`#[[2]]` contains `OutputStream` of the incoming socket

```
<<SocketLink`;
CreateAsynchronousServer[CreateServerSocket@12345,(#[[2]]~Write~"Hello world";Close/@#)&]
```

Comment: Wolfram? Link to language page?

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 83 bytes

```
require'socket';s=TCPServer.new 12345;loop{t=s.accept;t<<"Hello, World\n";t.close}
```